# FDB Client failing to start on macOS Catalina (v10.15.6)

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server, foundationdb

while trying to do a setup of local installation of janusgraph-fdb on my local MacBook.
But after the setup as I started **gremlin-server.sh**, I am getting this issue.
steps I followed:

1. **Installed FoundationDB.pkg (v6.2.20)** on **macOS Catalina (v10.15.6)** (both CLIENT and Server)
2. downloaded and unzipped **Janusgraph-foundationdb-adapter (v0.1.0)**
3. downloaded and unzipped **Janusgraph (v0.3.2)**
4. ran fdb adapter over janusgraph....

> *Janusgraph-foundationdb-adapter-dir*/**install.sh** *Janusgraph-dir*

5. tried starting *gremlin-server.sh*... it is failing with the following error.

*(This error is not coming in lower versions of macOS.)*

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/0g/45y2_pyn5994wjtlmjdlkq900000gn/T/fdbjni5991122741590979924.library: dlopen(/private/var/folders/0g/45y2_pyn5994wjtlmjdlkq900000gn/T/fdbjni5991122741590979924.library, 1): Library not loaded: libfdb_c.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/0g/45y2_pyn5994wjtlmjdlkq900000gn/T/fdbjni5991122741590979924.library
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.apple.foundationdb.JNIUtil.loadLibrary(JNIUtil.java:106)
    at com.apple.foundationdb.FDB.<clinit>(FDB.java:97)
    at com.experoinc.janusgraph.diskstorage.foundationdb.FoundationDBStoreManager.<init>(FoundationDBStoreManager.java:72)
```

These are my stacks:

1. FoundationDB.pkg (v6.2.20)
2. Janusgraph-foundationdb-adapter (v0.1.0)
3. Janusgraph (v0.3.2)
4. macOS Catalina (v10.15.6)

Answer (score 1):

Below mentioned steps worked for me :

1. Copy `libfdb_c.dylib` in your directory.
2. Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` as Environment Variable.